# Как из имеющихся изображений в виде массивов, создать сетку этих изображений 3x3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, numpy, pillow

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

empty_img = Image.open('xo_images/empty.jpg')
empty_img = np.asarray(empty_img, dtype = 'uint8')
full_img = np.array([], dtype = 'uint8')
for i in range(9):
    np.append(full_img, empty_img)
img = Image.fromarray(full_img, 'RGB')

img.save('xo_full.jpg')
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Очевидно, метод fromarray не понимает, что сделать с переданным в него одномерным массивом из массивов-изображений. Вам нужно сначала средствами numpy склеить все 9 изображений в одно, а потом уже передавать в fromarray.

Comment: @insolor, это очевидно, но я не понимаю какой нужно использовать метод для этого. Я уже попробовал несколько способов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image

#размерность сетки изображений
y = 3
x = 3

empty_img = Image.open('xo_images/empty.jpg')
width, height = empty_img.size #Размер изображения

img = Image.new('RGB', (width*x, height*y))

for w in range(0,x):
    for h in range(0,y):
        img.paste(empty_img, (width*w, height*h))

img.save('xo_full.jpg')
```

Результат:

[image: Решение]